# C++ class template inheritance and operator =

Tags: c++

I have an "assignable" object derived from a template class. But this object's assignment operator is not properly called even though the types are clearly defined.

```cpp
#include "stdio.h"

template <bool any>
struct Base {
    void operator = ( const Base& arr ) { printf("base = base\n"); }
};

// definition in advance
template <bool any> struct Assignable_A;

template <bool any>
struct A : public Base<any> {
    Assignable_A<any> operator [] (int i) { Assignable_A<true> b; return b; }
};

template <bool any>
struct Assignable_A : public A<any> {
    template <bool other>
    void operator = ( const A<other>& a ) { printf("Assignable_A = A<other>\n"); }
    template <bool other>
    void operator = ( const Assignable_A<other>& b ) { printf("Assignable_A = Assignable_A<other>\n"); }
};

int main() {
    A<true> a;
    a[1] = a;    // Assignable_A<true> = A<true>
    a[1] = a[0]; // Assignable_A<true> = Assignable_A<true>
    return 0;
};
```

I would like to code to output

```
Assignable_A = A<other>
Assignable_A = Assignable_A<other>
```

Yet, the actual output is

```sh
Assignable_A = A<other>
base = base
```

Why is `Assignable_A::operator =` not being called in the second call? (compiled with g++ 7.3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [copy_assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) (emphasise mine):

> A copy assignment operator of class T is a **non-template** non-static member function with the name `operator=` that takes exactly one parameter of type `T`, `T&`, `const T&`, `volatile T&`, or `const volatile T&`.

And

> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare one as an inline public member of the class.

So your **template** `operator=` is not the copy assignement, so compiler generates one.

To have your expected result, you have to provide:

```
void operator = ( const Assignable_A& b ) { // Assignable_A<any>
    printf("Assignable_A = Assignable_A<other>\n");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e456da52f0e9a866)

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, it appears accurate and useful to me

Comment: I didn't downvote, but that suggested replacement is not the same.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Because of the downvote, I provided some source and demo. (I would did the same with comment BTW).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: it is not a replacement, but an additional overload. (The other one could be simplified as template parameter is only `bool`, but that is an other story).

Comment: Hmm yeah okay I think I see. The whole thing is breaking my brain a bit tbh; think it's the names, or the contrived nature of the example

Comment: @MooingDuck earlier explanation was not sufficient to explain the question so was downvoted and as `Jarod42` said that downvote helped him as feedback and he added examples after that. 
That being said, I agree a comment should be added to explain the reason behind downvote.

Comment: @Jarod42  keeping above explanation in mind , why `a[1] = a;` invokes 
```    template <bool other>
    void operator = ( const A<other>& a ) { printf("Assignable_A = A<other>\n"); }
```
that too is not copy assignment operator (as it is templatized )

Comment: We have 3 candidates `void operator = ( const A<other>&)` (#1), `void operator = ( const Assignable<other>&)`(#2) `void operator = ( const Assignable<any>& a )` (#3). As `a[0]` is `Assignable<any>`, all are viable candidate, best match is #3. As `a` is `A<any>`, only #1 is viable.